# Dual-boot and two hard drivers sees only one

Tags: dual-boot

I'm trying to install both windows 7 and ubuntu. I have two hard drive:
- 256 GB SSD
- 1TB HDD

I created two partition from SSD  - 130 GB, 120 GB
HDD is whole one partition 1TB

I installed win7 on 130 GB HDD partition and when i'm trying install ubuntu in LiveMode i see ony one disc HDD and my both partition 130 and 120 don't show in installation mode. But when i use gparted there are all partition and disc shown but i can't choose any partition of ssd in install disc list beacuse they don't appear there. Any of you can help?

Edit: Added screen
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH3an.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant of the installer window showing the drives. Keep that one in too through

Comment: It is on the screen. that is the window second one bellow

Comment: There is only one 1TB ATA Toshiba

Comment: Sorry again. The image didn't load in fully. Instead if the "install alongside" option, try the "Something Else" one.

Comment: yee but i need win7 too

Comment: Oh, don't worry about that. Something Else just lets you choose where exactly you want to install Ubuntu. Don't choose any of the Erase options.

Comment: LOL i try to start system as try it and must 6 times restart computer before the system started working. 

I tryied "Something else" i saw all partition i choose the one which i was interested in, i chose file system ext4 (and 2,3, ntfs) and when i press install i'm getting error: "No root file system is defined" "Please correct this from partition menu"

Comment: format the one you want as `ext4`. Right click the partition, go into its properties, mount it as `/`

Comment: as /home /boot shouldn't work? because i've tryied those two and nothing happened

Comment: /home and /. There's more to the filesystem than /home and /boot

Comment: One more thing, is the format disc where i want to install ubuntu is needed?

Comment: Format partition, not disk. If you format the disk, that'll erase everything on it

Comment: Ok, but after i install ubuntu on this partition is there any posibility to resize this partition?

Comment: Yes, of course, but it's better to get your desired sizes beforehand. Do that in Gparted.